# Unable to set alias in PowerShell using a string

Tags: powershell

I tried to set an alias in PowerShell by running `Set-Alias -Name artisan -Value 'php aritsan'`, though the command ran successfully but when I call the alias the following error occurs :

```bsh
artisan : The term 'php aritsan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ artisan
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php aritsan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What's the correct way to go for?

P.S: `artisan` is a file in the current directory. The file is packaged with laravel framework

Comment: AFAIK You cannot include a parameter in an alias what would be the case if you provide 2 string seperated by a space. You may create a function to run the desired command including the parameter.

Answer (score 6):

This will help you create an alias for "php artisan" in Windows PowerShell Globally.
Just follow these steps and its done.

1. First of all search powershell using win+S and run it as administrator and then paste this code and hit Enter.

   if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE )) {New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force }
2. Then run this command.

   notepad $profile
3. A notepad file will open. Paste this code in notepad file and hit ctrl+S

   Function CD32($arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5) {php artisan $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5}
   Set-Alias -Name pa -Value CD32
4. And then finally paste this command on your powershell and hit enter.

   Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

And it's done. Now you can use "pa" as an alias for "php artisan" globally in your windows powershell.

[Here I am using "pa" on my VS Code PowerShell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ66P.png)

Answer (score 0):

All the details are described in:

- `Get-Help alias -ShowWindow` shows all available help for alias
- `Get-Help Set-Alias` show specific help for Set-Alias

An alias is an alternate name or nickname for a cmdlet or for a command
element, such as a function, script, file, or executable file. You
can use the alias instead of the command name in any Windows PowerShell
commands.

You can assign an alias to a cmdlet, script, function, or executable file.
However, you cannot assign an alias to a command and its parameters.
For example, you can assign an alias to the Get-Eventlog cmdlet, but you
cannot assign an alias to the "`Get-Eventlog -LogName System`" command.

However, you can create a function that includes the command. To create a
function, type the word "function" followed by a name for the function.
Type the command, and enclose it in braces ({}).

For example, the following command creates the syslog function. This
function represents the "`Get-Eventlog -LogName System`" command:

`function syslog {Get-Eventlog -LogName System}`

You can now type "syslog" instead of the command. And, you can create
aliases for the syslog function.

For more information about functions, type:

`Get-Help about_Functions`

Answer (score 0):

1. hold shift and right click on start button
2. open terminal as admin
3. past this code and hint enter

`if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE )) {New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force }`

4. then `notepad $profile`
5. in notepad past this code:

`function art($arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5) { php artisan $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5} Set-Alias a art`

6. Ctrl + S and close notepad
7. List item